# The best way to break generator into chunks

Tags: php, foreach, generator, chunks

Can you help me to write this code that breaks generator yields into the chunks by 100 and save them into database more beautiful.

```
$batchSize = 100;

$batch = [];
$i = 0;

/** 
 * @yield array $item
 */
foreach(itemsGenerator() as $item) {
    $batch[] = $item;
    $i++;

    if ($i === $batchSize) {
        Db::table('items')->save($batch);

        $batch = [];
        $i = 0;
    }

    $cnt++;
}

if ($batch) {
     Db::table('items')->save($batch);
}
```

I don't want to put the logic of breaking into chunks in `itemsGenerator`

Comment: Perhaps better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 12):

You can put the chunk logic into a separate reusable function.

### Solution 1: Every chunk is a generator.

https://3v4l.org/3eSQm

```
function chunk(\Generator $generator, $n) {
    for ($i = 0; $generator->valid() && $i < $n; $generator->next(), ++$i) {
        yield $generator->current();
    }
}

function foo() {
  for ($i = 0; $i < 11; ++$i) {
    yield $i;
  }
}

for ($gen = foo(); $gen->valid();) {
    $chunk = [];
    foreach (chunk($gen, 3) as $value) {
        $chunk[] = $value;
    }
    print json_encode($chunk) . "\n";
}
```

### Solution 2: Every chunk is an array.

https://3v4l.org/aSfeR

```
function generator_chunks(\Generator $generator, $max_chunk_size) {
  $chunk = [];
  foreach ($generator as $item) {
    $chunk[] = $item;
    // @todo A local variable might be faster than count(), but adds clutter to the code. So using count() for this example code.
    if (count($chunk) >= $max_chunk_size) {
      yield $chunk;
      $chunk = [];
    }
  }
  if ([] !== $chunk) {
      // Remaining chunk with fewer items.
      yield $chunk;
  }
}

function generator() {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 11; ++$i) {
        yield $i;
    }
}

foreach (generator_chunks(generator(), 3) as $chunk) {
    print json_encode($chunk) . "\n";
}
```

Now all of one chunk will be in memory at once as an array, but not the entire sequence.

There might be ways to make each chunk behave like a generator. But this is a different story for another day.